# Your session has expired. on ajax form post laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following html snippit from my view and js code to handel the form request.

```js
$('#quick-enquiry').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".submit").prop("disabled", true);
  data = $(this).serialize();
  action = $(this).attr('action');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: action,
    data: data,
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {
        $("#quick-enquiry").trigger("reset");
        $('.print-error-msg').find('ul').empty();
        $('.print-error-msg').css('display', 'block');
        $("#response-msg").toggleClass('uk-alert-danger uk-alert-success');
        $('.print-error-msg').find('ul').append("<li>" + data.success + "</li>");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.print-error-msg').fadeOut();
          $(".submit").prop("disabled", false);
          UIkit.modal("#modal-quick-enquiry").hide();
        }, 3000);
      } else {
        printMessageErrors(data.error);
      }
    }
  });
});

function printMessageErrors(msg) {
  $('.print-error-msg').find('ul').empty();
  $('.print-error-msg').css('display', 'block');
  $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
    $('.print-error-msg').find('ul').append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.26/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.26/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="{{ route('frontend-postEnquiry') }}" method="POST" id="quick-enquiry">
  <input type="hidden" id="tour-id" value="1">
  <div class="uk-margin">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Full Name</label>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
      <input class="uk-input uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="fullName" name="fullName">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="uk-margin">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Email</label>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
      <input class="uk-input uk-form-width-large" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-margin">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Message</label>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
      <textarea class="uk-textarea uk-form-width-large" rows="4" placeholder="Some Message...." id="enquiryMessage" name="enquiryMessage"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="uk-text-right">
    <button class="uk-modal-close-default" type="button" uk-close></button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary submit uk-width-1-1" type="submit">Send</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

With the above code I'm getting

**419
Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.**

I've set CSRF-TOKEN in ajax and in head section also, but seems like my js code is not picking up csrf token.

I would be very thankful if anyone could highlight the mistake I've made above.

Comment: Is the `<meta>` tag definitely in the page?

Comment: @RossWilson yes it there you can confirm at this link. `https://crusadehimalaya.com/` And  ajax form is in `https://crusadehimalaya.com/trip/everest-base-camp-trek` quick enquiry button.

Comment: Is this error showing as a whole page or is it just a response from the ajax request?

Comment: @RossWilson it is showing in whole page.

Comment: @RossWilson my jquery is not picking up the my form.

Comment: It's possible that the reason it's not working is because you have two elements on the page with an id of `quick-enquiry`. I would suggest changing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:
`{{ csrf_field() }}` instead of `@csrf`

419 error is mostly because of CSRF token issues.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @geek. but I'm trying getting csrf token from meta tag via meta tag.